# SVG path created with JS doesnt show

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to create/draw paths (lines) in a SVG using Javascript. But for some reason the lines don't show, even though the html is generated. Is there something i am missing, can you have a look at my code and tell me why it doesn't show?

1. This is mz JS code

   ```
        //add lines from layerborderbot to ldescborderbot
        var _Ldesc = document.createElement('svg');
        _Ldesc.style.cssText = `position:absolute;left:calc(26vw + 3px);top:calc(66mm + 2px);width:calc(2.1vw + 1px);height:${scaleLength(Math.ceil(layerTotalLengthN)*100)}cm;`;
        for (x = 0; layer_anzahl > x; x++) {
            var _lineLdesc = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'path'); //Create a path in SVG's namespace
        var tempPos; var tempHeight; var tY; var tH;
        if(typeof positionLith[x+1] === 'undefined' && dHdesc[x] < 0) {tY = cm2px(parseFloat(scaleLength(layerTotalLengthN*100))); tH = cm2px(dHdesc[x]);}
        else  { tY = cm2px(scaleLength(parseFloat(lith_to[x+1])*100));}
        if(dHdesc[x] > 0) { tY = cm2px(scaleLength(parseFloat(lith_to[x])*100)); tH = cm2px(getlayersize(x));}
        else {  if (x==0 && dHdesc[0]<0) { tH = cm2px(realHeightLdesc[x] - getlayersize(x));}
                else if (x==0 && dHdesc[0]>0) { tH = cm2px(getlayersize(x));}
                else {
                    if(occupyDesc[x] > 0) { tH = cm2px(occupyDesc[x]-getlayersize(x));}
                    else { tH = cm2px(realHeightLdesc[x]-getlayersize(x));} 
                }
            }


            _lineLdesc.setAttribute("d",`M 0 ${tY} L ${vw2px(2.1)} ${tH}`); //Set path's data
        _lineLdesc.style.stroke = "#000"; //Set stroke colour
        _lineLdesc.style.strokeWidth = "1"; //Set stroke width
        _Ldesc.appendChild(_lineLdesc);
   ```
2. This is the HTML output (from chrome console)

```
     <svg style="position: absolute; left: calc(26vw + 3px); top: calc(251.449px); width: calc(2.1vw + 1px); height: 12cm;">
     <path d="M 0 151.18110426684856 L 33 151.18110426684856" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1;"></path>
     <path d="M 0 434.64567476718963 L 33 15.807083450280626" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1;"></path>
     <path d="M 0 434.64567476718963 L 33 226.77165640027278" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1;"></path>
     </svg>
```

Comment: I believe if your going to create an SVG in code, you need to specify the namespace using `createElementNS`..  eg.. `document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");`

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify a viewBox, so it defaults to 300x150.

Yet the 3 Lines you draw require a `viewBox="0 0 34 435"` to show **all** of those Lines:

[image]

```html
<style>
svg{
  height:180px;
  background:pink;
}
</style>
<svg viewBox="0 0 34 435" stroke-width="3">
     <path d="M 0 151.1  L 33 151.1" stroke="blue"></path>
     <path d="M 0 434.6  L 33 15.8"  stroke="red"></path>
     <path d="M 0 434.6  L 33 226.7" stroke="green"></path>
</svg>
```